# How can I force Selenium to control MiniBrowser?

Tags: c#, selenium, safari, webdriver, webkit

I'm trying to automate some cross-browser website testing for my employer. Currently, we have a small C#-xUnit-Selenium testing suite for End-to-End tests. My goal is to run these tests locally on Windows using Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. The first two browsers I'm not worried about. Safari is giving me the trouble.

Since Safari doesn't support Win10, I've opted to use a WebKit-powered browser as a substitute. I know it won't be a 1-1 match, but I'm not concerned by the differences. My browser of choice is MiniBrowser, emulating Safari 15 with a very recent build of Webkit port WinCairo.

Here's my current problem: **I don't know how to force Selenium to control MiniBrowser.**

I would really like to have a class in Selenium that could parallel ChromeDriver() or SafariDriver() (WinCairoDriver(), I guess). But I don't know how to create it. I know that both WinCairo and MiniBrowser implement a WebDriver.exe file in their bin folders,
but I don't know how to translate that file into a driver class Selenium can recognize. I'm sure there are other requirements as well to get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Guide I used to build WinCairo browser](https://james.darpinian.com/blog/safari-on-windows#:%7E:text=Safari%20doesn%27t%20run%20on,because%20iTunes%20still%20supports%20Windows)

[Link to my built WinCairo MiniBrowser](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vmAoQODYU81MTDA7I29SaYhP1d2KLQvL/view?usp=drivesdk)

Here's where I would insert said WinCairoDriver() class if it existed:

```
namespace Project_Tests.Fixtures
{
    public class DriverSetup : IDisposable
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        public DriverSetup()
        {
            new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
            
            var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            // I need help here:
            //var wincairoDriver = new WinCairoDriver();

            driver = chromeDriver; // Where I want to pass wincairoDriver;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If MiniBrowser is based on Webkit, have you tried using the Webkit driver for Selenium?

Comment: I have not, where can I find it? It doesn't appear to be in the OpenQA.Selenium package I'm using.

Comment: One thing I noticed was that double-clicking bin64/WebBrowser.exe did not open MiniBrowser. This is different from how chromeDriver behaves on my machine. Double-clicking chromeDriver opens Chrome. This issue worries me because AFAIK that WebDriver.exe should control MiniBrowser.